# Does OneDrive change/re-encode jpg files?

Tags: android, onedrive

I have encountered a strange problem I am unable to debug. An image is uploaded to Onedrive via some code very similar to the given example, and once uploaded, the image is visible in the OneDrive web interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659727.aspx

Upon trying to download it, again using code from the example, the following line of code

Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

also returns a null value for bMap.  I know these files (which I obtain from copying from the Android Clipboard and writing to a file on disk) are valid, b/c I use them in Gridview elements and upload/download them to Dropbox in a similar way.

Is there some kind of jpg re-encoding performed in OneDrive (like RGB->CKMY conversion) what would no longer prevent them from working?

Also, is there some other type of query parameter like "/picture?type=thumbnail" or "/picture?type=normal" that needs to be appended to a file.XXXX OneDrive ID that would prevent any possible conversion?

Is there a way to debug exactly why the BitmapFactory.decodeStream() function fails, like debugging output?

EDIT:  So, I came across the following SO post, and figured out this is the same problem I am having.

[OneDrive - Wrong size for PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906007/onedrive-wrong-size-for-png-files)

For a certain file, if I download it using the Onedrive SDK and look at the stream length

```
public void onDownloadCompleted(LiveDownloadOperation operation) {
  int length = operation.getContentLength();
}
```

it reports a size of 2723 bytes, but if I download the file and save it using a desktop web browser, the file is 1837 bytes.  Is there something I am missing about reading the size of a stream, or is the API just broken?

Comment: If you download the binary content and save it to a file, does that file open correctly in a program capable of rendering images?

Comment: It sounds like you images are indeed being converted and down sampled, but I'm unclear why you are unable to decode them on the device.  I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question apparently is, there is a bug in the Onedrive SDK.  I ended up filing an issue on Github with Microsoft, and it turns out they discovered that with certain types of small images (and potentially PDFs), the actually file size being transmitted back after a download is wrong.

https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android/issues/37#issuecomment-65457177

It's all just a weird artifact of the way I was testing my app.  Since Chrome for Android is the only app I've discovered that lets you copy an image to the clipboard, I was just Google search to find images (tiny thumbnail images in the basic web search results), and copying those to the clipboard.  Had I been using larger images, I may never have run across this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented behaviour as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659726.aspx (see the first note under uploading).

You can disable conversion by adding `downsize_photo_uploads=false` to your query string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it out though, and it doesn't seem to make a difference or solve the issue.

Comment: Have you had a look at the response when you download it to ensure the body is a valid JPEG?

I think you're experiencing two or three issues here:
- Incorrect size reported by API
- Re-encoded JPEG on upload
- Possibly getting an error or something upon retrieval from the API, causing your decoder to break

Comment: Particularly have a look at the status code. Android's documentation says 'If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null' in regards to your factory. That means the API isn't giving you a valid image and you should look into the response in more depth to find out why.

Comment: Make sure you're uploading with downsize_photo_uploads=false. The API size issue reports the wrong size in the API metadata request but doesn't alter the size of the content stream we send back when you download the file. If you upload the file with the query string attribute set, you download exactly the same set of bytes you uploaded.