# Getting file contents with Range header returns Partial Content and subsequent request returns no data

Tags: onedrive

We have a non-understandable issue with getting file contents using OneDrive API.

When we request file contents with Range header:

```
GET /blahblah/foobar.docx HTTP/1.1
Host: qw122q-ch3301.files.1drv.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Range: bytes=0-77270
```

OneDrive returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 18325
```

We checked that the file size is correct on OneDrive server using web interface. Usually OneDrive returns full requested content but from last week they returns partial contents. But it's OK if we can get remaining parts with another API calls.

But when we send another request with Range header:

```
Range: bytes=18325-77270
```

OneDrive returns no data:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
```

Has anyone experienced this issue? I can't find any clues on this issue from OneDrive developer documents. Please shed some light on this..

Comment: This is definitely unexpected behavior - can you reproduce this problem with other file types, or only work docs?

Comment: @Brad I think we found why it happens. This problem happens after modifying office files using online version of office. After the modification it seems that the file size changed but OneDrive API returns original file size.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the investigation! Do you mind sharing the `id` of one of the documents that you're seeing this behavior with?

Comment: Not at all. It's a sample document. Document ID is 3B6BF82215387F3E!1190.

Comment: @Brad Any updates?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - we're just back at work and catching up on the holiday events :). I'll take a look at this a little more this week, but it would be useful if you could provide the `Content-Range` headers from the responses as well.

Comment: No problem. Happy New Year! :) From the response, Content-Length is 18325 and Content-Range is bytes 0-18324/18325.

Comment: We requested with Range: bytes=0-77270.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have a theory so I'm going to take a shot at an answer. There are actually two different issues that are resulting in this confusing behavior, so I'll tackle each one separately.

**Reported file size doesn't match content size**

> This is an unfortunate quirk of the system that is being tracked with [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/123). Ryan explains in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906007/onedrive-wrong-size-for-png-files).

**Range downloads of word docs do not correctly handle unsatisfiable ranges**

> When a range outside of the actual file size is requested we should be failing with a `416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable` like we do for "normal" files. But that's obviously not working. You can see in the `Content-Range` of the result there's something screwy going on:
>
> `FileSize: 15 bytes`
>   `Range Requested: bytes=15-`
>   `Content-Range Response: bytes=15-14/15`
>
> The value of the `Content-Range` obviously makes no sense.

Together these two issues should result in the weird behavior you're seeing. We're close to resolving the first, while the second was unknown (at least to me) so I've opened a [new GitHub issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/495) to track it.