# Drive item size is wrong after upload of plain text file to OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

When [uploading files to OneDrive for Business using the Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I sometimes see that the drive item has the wrong size after the `PUT` request. I know that OneDrive might modify Office files on the fly but I see it happening for plain text files too.

In example below I write the string `first version` (13 bytes) to a new drive item.

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!e8-Jy2tSiUy2AJBZzvZxc3DIh8dRoG9DrM6MEcF_oxinj1yhH9A8RYDHeCfkxipc/items/root:/onedrive-public-kuvgpshldglnfidf.
txt:/content
```

Don't think it matters but I set the `Content-Type` header to `application/octet-stream`. Graph API returns status code 201 (as expected) and the response:

```json
{
 "@odata.context": "https:\/\/graph.microsoft.com\/v1.0\/$metadata#drives('b%21e8-Jy2tSiUy2AJBZzvZxc3DIh8dRoG9DrM6MEcF_oxinj1yhH9A8RYDHeCfkxipc')\/items\/$entity",
 "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https:\/\/REDACTED.sharepoint.com\/sites\/go-test-onedrive-kuvgpshldglnfidf\/_layouts\/15\/download.aspx?UniqueId=ce025490-d7ee-438a-ac00-a817784e7ea7&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.Nm1lSTJML0U1N2dVSzZ2L2MwbkVoc3Fnc0pkbk4wZ0psM1FsWFArWHdTND0&ApiVersion=2.0",
 "createdDateTime": "2020-09-07T07:13:03Z",
 "eTag": "\"{CE025490-D7EE-438A-AC00-A817784E7EA7},1\"",
 "id": "013OPAMZEQKQBM53WXRJB2YAFIC54E47VH",
 "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-09-07T07:13:03Z",
 "name": "onedrive-public-kuvgpshldglnfidf.txt",
 "webUrl": "https:\/\/REDACTED.sharepoint.com\/sites\/go-test-onedrive-kuvgpshldglnfidf\/Delade%20dokument\/onedrive-public-kuvgpshldglnfidf.txt",
 "cTag": "\"c:{CE025490-D7EE-438A-AC00-A817784E7EA7},1\"",
 "size": 26,
 "createdBy": {
  "application": {
   "id": "9c557449-f2f5-4c73-a638-818eb86aad98",
   "displayName": "REDACTED"
  }
 },
 "lastModifiedBy": {
  "application": {
   "id": "9c557449-f2f5-4c73-a638-818eb86aad98",
   "displayName": "REDACTED"
  }
 },
 "parentReference": {
  "driveId": "b!e8-Jy2tSiUy2AJBZzvZxc3DIh8dRoG9DrM6MEcF_oxinj1yhH9A8RYDHeCfkxipc",
  "driveType": "documentLibrary",
  "id": "013OPAMZF6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
  "path": "\/drives\/b!e8-Jy2tSiUy2AJBZzvZxc3DIh8dRoG9DrM6MEcF_oxinj1yhH9A8RYDHeCfkxipc\/root:"
 },
 "file": {
  "mimeType": "text\/plain",
  "hashes": {
   "quickXorHash": "ZkiDHOZABxDYoQxylUMa3uAGAAA="
  }
 },
 "fileSystemInfo": {
  "createdDateTime": "2020-09-07T07:13:03Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-09-07T07:13:03Z"
 }
}
```

Notice how drive item size is 26 and not 13 as expected. The drive item size is still 26 if I fetch the drive item using a `GET` request. If I follow the download URL I get the correct `Content-Length` header though:

```sh
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" $DOWNLOADURL
...
< HTTP/2 200 
< cache-control: private
< content-length: 13
< content-type: text/plain
...
first version
```

Is it possible to get the correct drive item size directly without having to check the `Content-Length` header when following the download URL?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload the file in the OneDrive, then it will add additional metadata to Office documents after you upload (not the file types though). I remember a related thread on this, discussing about this - [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_win10-mso_o365b/files-are-different-sizes-when-stored-in-onedrive/b0dae46f-2f68-4948-a099-07c063eaaf2c).

Comment: It feels like a OneDrive bug in this case, as it's a plain text file and the drive item size doesn't match the file size after download. I found [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906007/onedrive-wrong-size-for-png-files) where they discuss a similar issue. If it's not a bug it should be documented more clearly I think. I created [a microsoft-graph-docs github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9776).

Comment: wonderful @tomyl. I would do the same as well...!! Glad that you did so. Hope they can fix/update it.